# What are recent advances in relational databases?

Tags: sql, database, relational-database, relational, relational-algebra

I'm wondering what are recent advances in relational database theory and related domains? I'm interested in new approaches, query languages (alternatives to SQL and/or extensions to it), products (proprietary and open source, though I'm much more interested in open source) and research projects developed in last years.

Comment: Might be worth asking on http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Not sure if that question relates to administration of databases...

Comment: @andreypopp: Nor is it a specific coding question, so it's not really appropriate here.

Comment: Any suggestion for SE site to move this question on? Thought I think this question conforms to SO faq — "if your question generally covers… software tools commonly used by programmers, matters that are unique to the programming profession" howerer I agree this question is a bit scientific...

Comment: It's a question related to computer science... Is there any SE site for that?

Comment: This question at Theoretical Computer Science: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/8471/1337

Answer (score 0):

I am not versed in the subject but there was a very nice project based on XML structures over RDB that caught my eye a few years back and now seems to work perfectly.

Have a look at http://exist.sourceforge.net/ to see a nice approach to RDB used to build a more flexible storage system with XQuery as the query language. You should like it, it's open source.